# Get the last insert id with doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, lastinsertid

How can I get the last insert id with doctrine 2 ORM? I didn't find this in the documentation of doctrine, is this even possible?

Comment: try this, at the end of your insert return the id... like return $this->id;

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I had to use this after the flush to get the last insert id:

```
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
$user->getId();
```

Comment: Cant use it. Getting error Call to undefined method Test\Entity\Test::getId() in "My Project"

Comment: @noobie-php You need to define a public getter for your Id (if this one is private as it should be)

Comment: @cheesemacfly: I already sorted this out this error is generated (in my scenario) when we are unable To flush() for any reason, once Flush() is executed successfully getID() starts working, assuming getter and setters are not a issue here

Comment: What if I `persist()` the entity in a loop and `flush()` after that? I'm trying to figure that out, but no luck so far.

Comment: assign id to variable : `code` $id = $user->getId(); `code`

Answer (score 46):

You can access the id after calling the persist and flush methods of the entity manager.

```
$widgetEntity = new WidgetEntity();
$entityManager->persist($widgetEntity);
$entityManager->flush();
$widgetEntity->getId();
```

You *must* call flush in order to get this id.

Answer (score 35):

If you're not using entities but Native SQL as shown [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) then you might want to get the last inserted id as shown below:

```php
$entityManager->getConnection()->lastInsertId()
```

For databases with sequences such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) please note that you can provide the sequence name as the first parameter of the `lastInsertId` method.

```php
$entityManager->getConnection()->lastInsertId($seqName = 'my_sequence')
```

For more information take a look at the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/03e17189c48a92bff9c5fd7d9242d13a15780d15/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L1145) and [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/cd11723e6310b5973f50e7d9819c58916721d290/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Id/IdentityGenerator.php#L41).

Comment: This might not work with every DBMS. For instance it does not work with Postgres (because of sequences)

Comment: Awesome!! I spent hours looking for this little snippet.

Comment: @paul.ago You just need to know the name of the sequence, eg: `lastInsertId('articles_id_seq')`

Comment: You can also get the name of the sequence like this: `$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();` `$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('\App\Entity\YourClass');` `$seqName = $metadata->getSequenceName($conn->getDatabasePlatform());` Works :-)

Answer (score 10):

Calling flush() can potentially add lots of new entities, so there isnt really the notion of "lastInsertId". However Doctrine will populate the identity fields whenever one is generated, so accessing the id field after calling flush will always contain the ID of a newly "persisted" entity.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to answer the question. But,

If it's a MySQL database

should `$doctrine_record_object->id` work if `AUTO_INCREMENT` is defined in database and in your table definition.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, as I declared $id as private I just created a new public method to get it.

```
public function getId() {
 return $this->id;
}
```

So then I could call it like so

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername("Kylo Ren");
    $entityManager = getEntityManager();
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();
    echo "Created User with ID " . $user->getId() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i post my code, after i have pushed myself for one working day to find this solution.

**Function to get the last saved record :**

```
private function getLastId($query) {
        $conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lastId = $stmt->fetch()['id'];
        return $lastId;
    }
```

**Another Function which call the above function**

```
private function clientNum() {
        $lastId = $this->getLastId("SELECT id FROM client ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $noClient = 'C' . sprintf("%06d", $lastId + 1); // C000002 if the last record ID is 1
        return $noClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple: `SELECT max(id) FROM client`

Comment: Not a good idea for concurrent and big systems.